# Собственные Яндекс.Пробки

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Можно ли как-то нарисовать на yandex maps собственные яндекс пробки, то что делает яндекс карты, только хочу использовать свои данные для отрисовки?

Comment: Яндекс рисует "скоростными" цветами собственные графы дорог. Если вы хотите отдельные участки дорог раскрасить, используйте ломаные линии и рисуйте их полупрозрачными, например, поверх карты. Если не подходит, объясните детальней, что есть, что будет, как это использовать планируется.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
Планирую сделать, что-то вроде яндекс.плохие дороги, показывать цветом плохие и хорошие места дорог. Вроде как механизм отрисовки яндекс.пробок полностью подходит, нужно только данные свои вставить.

[Что-то вроде такого](https://medium.com/@percepsense/intelligent-pothole-detection-879ef635dd38)

Comment: Тогда или линии свои или слой свой добавляйте на карту Яндекса — зависит от ваших методов сбора и хранения данных, а также количества этих нужных линий.

Comment: @YaCor' благодарю, остановлюсь пока на полилайнах